# Как скрыть содержание JS скрипта в инспекторе

Tags: javascript, hide

Как скрыть код JS скрипта в инспекторе. Видел такие скрипты - Сам скрипт в ресурсах есть, но кода нет, но вот как сделать не знаю.

Может иные пути по скрытию кода в скриптах, может сами скрипты скрывать.

Comment: Можно пример того что вы видели? скрыть или просто минифицыровать хотите?

Comment: Если скрипт был скрит, то как вы его могли видеть?

Comment: @iksuy читаете что написано? код, а не сам скрипт

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan не могу привести пример ибо дело было давно. Именно скрыть содержимое. Сам скрипт виден в ресурсах, но кода нет.

Comment: значит и файл пустой, такого не может быть

Comment: "скрипт" это у вас видимо файл, а "код" - это его содержимое. JS не обязательно будет написан прямо в html, он может быть написан в отдельно подгружаемых файлах

Comment: @iksuy да ладно? а то я не знал.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan хорошо. есть ли возможность как-то скрыть скрипт?

Comment: Есть вариант "сокрытия" обфускация называется. (Запутывания, код меняется до неузнаваемости так, что его становится сложно повторно использовать или разобраться в нём)

Comment: Второй вариант - можно разпаковывать/разшифровывать и выполнять частями, но при желание и это можно обойти, т.к. всёравно "процессор JS" принимает только разшифрованый код.

Answer (score 0):

Прячем, обфусцируем и криптуем клиентскую часть веб-приложений

https://habrahabr.ru/company/xakep/blog/128741/